NIntegrate with depended variables
I have problems in integrating a function with depended variables. I am pasting the code below
SP[T_]:=If[w <= wcritical[T], NIntegrate[w*F1[w, T], {w,0, wcritical[T], Method -> {"LocalAdaptive"}], NIntegrate[w*F2[w, T], {w, wcritical[T],Min[N[T/2, T]]}, Method -> {"LocalAdaptive"}]] /; T > 100

Where wcritical[T] is a previously defined function. However since SP is not a function of both T and w, the code won't calculate. SP must be only T depended.
Thanks in advance!

Your code doesn't make sense, since w is the integration variable, which is scoped in NIntegrate, so the outer If cannot know anything about it. Reading between the lines of what you are trying to do, perhaps it should be rather SP[T_] /; T > 100 :=   NIntegrate[w*F1[w, T], {w, 0, wcritical[T]},     Method -> {"LocalAdaptive"}] +    NIntegrate[w*F2[w, T], {w, wcritical[T], Min[N[T/2, T]]},     Method -> {"LocalAdaptive"}]

Also, there is a problem with the bound Min[N[T/2, T]]:

if you want to select the smaller of T/2 and T it should be Min[N[{T/2, T}]]
Since you are requiring T>100, the above will always evaluate to T/2


Thank you very much for the replies!

I think this code should work: SP[T_] :=   Assuming[{T > 100},    If[w <= wcritical[T],     NIntegrate[w*F1[w, T], {w, 0, wcritical[T]},      Method -> "LocalAdaptive"],     NIntegrate[w*F2[w, T], {w, wcritical[T], Min[N[T/2, T]]},      Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]]] Try it
